# Fill struct in6_addr with unsigned char array

Tags: c++, dns, lookup

I'am doing *DNS lookup* tool in C++ and i am trying to get IPv6 from 
`unsigned char *` (where it is stored in non readable format), copy it to `struct in6_addr`, then i want to convert it and print it.

```
struct in6_addr tmp2;
char buf[41];
memcpy(tmp2.s6_addr, answ[i].rdata, 128); 
cout << answ[i].name << " IN AAAA " << inet_ntop(AF_INET6, tmp2.s6_addr, buf, 128) << endl;
```

My output should look like this,

```
www.domain.name.cz. IN AAAA 2001:67c:1220:809::93e5:917
```

but somehow it looks like this.

```
www.domain.name.cz IN AAAA 106:7c12:2008:900::
```

Generating RDATA

```
u_char *ReadName(unsigned char *readResponse, unsigned char *buffer, int *count) {
unsigned char *name;
unsigned int p = 0, jumped = 0, offset;
int i, j;

*count = 1;
name = (unsigned char *) malloc(256);

name[0] = '\0';

//read the names in 3www6google3com format
while (*readResponse != 0) {
    if (*readResponse >= 192) {
        offset = (*readResponse) * 256 + *(readResponse + 1) - 49152; //49152 = 11000000 00000000 ;)
        readResponse = buffer + offset - 1;
        jumped = 1; //we have jumped to another location so counting wont go up!
    } else {
        name[p++] = *readResponse;
    }

    readResponse = readResponse + 1;

    if (jumped == 0) {
        *count = *count + 1; //if we havent jumped to another location then we can count up
    }
}

name[p] = '\0'; //string complete
if (jumped == 1) {
    *count = *count + 1; //number of steps we actually moved forward in the packet
}

//now convert 3www6google3com0 to www.google.com
for (i = 0; i < (int) strlen((const char *) name); i++) {
    p = name[i];
    for (j = 0; j < (int) p; j++) {
        name[i] = name[i + 1];
        i = i + 1;
    }
    name[i] = '.';
}
name[i - 1] = '\0'; //remove the last dot
return name;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like a byte-order problem, at least. How are you generating rdata?

Comment: @stark I added function wich generate rdata

Comment: `in6_addr` takes a 16-byte binary IPv6 address, not a domain name string.